# What are the consequences of entering North Macedonia without an entry stamp?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, passport-stamps, eu-citizens, macedonia

I am walking on an EU passport through Kosovo, North Macedonia (via Tetovo and Skopje), and Bulgaria.

I seem to have messed up in my planning: there is no border crossing remotely close to where I want to cross the border in the Lumbardhi nature reserve, which is between Prevalle and Tetovo. However, I just met a British cyclist who didn't receive an entry stamp for Montenegro, and he said that the border guards didn't seem to notice it at exit. Is the situation likely to be similar for me at my exit from North Macedonia into Bulgaria?

NB, I would be eligible for an identification card which would be valid at the Macedonian border and which cannot receive stamps.

NB 2 I am attaching a copy of the Kosovan form to apply for a permit to cross the border away from official checkpoints for reference. If anybody is able to find the North Macedonian version, I would much appreciate it if you were able to attach it to one of your answers, so that I can email it to the relevant North Macedonian authorities! [image: The Kosovan application form for a permit to cross the border away from official checkpoints]

Comment: Even though North Macedonian allows entry with an EEA ID card and its border officials don't stamp EU/EFTA passports, that doesn't mean you can cross the border at any point! It's not an "open border". Stamp is not an issue, but if the border guards catch you crossing the border somewhere in a forest, you might spend a few days in detention and get a big fine. Absolutely not worth it.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Montenegro did not offer me an exit stamp; I asked and they said it wasn't necessary. Would you happen to know if Kosovo offers an exit stamp?

Comment: I don't, but Kosovo also allows entry with an EEA ID card (that can't be stamped). It's actually better than using a passport, due to tensions between Kosovo and Serbia.

Comment: @novice The Montenegrins were wrong, they DO have to stamp foreigners on entry and exit. Clearly stated in the relevant law. Same goes for Kosovo

Comment: @Johnnyjanko It's very specific: if last having entered Kosovo other than from Serbia, and then trying to travel Kosovo-Serbia, the Serbians will refuse entry as you entered Serbia "illegally" (with no current Serbian entry stamp). I've crossed half a dozen times with my ID card, and they only asked verbally where I entered Serbia. I usually say Surcin (Belgrade airport) and then I'm good

Comment: @Crazydre Right you are, but I didn't want to go into that much details, given that the OP hasn't mentioned Serbia at all.

Answer (score 5):

Article 18 of the [Macedonian law on border control](https://mvr.gov.mk/Upload/Documents/ZGK%20PRECISTEN.pdf) states only "third-country nationals" are stamped. Article 3(10) specifies that "third-country nationals" means nationalities other than Macedonian, EU or "equivalent" (meaning EFTA).

As such, you don't need a stamp even if using a passport.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passport_stamp, EU citizens do not seem to need an entry stamp in North Macedonia.

Comment: I'm behind that info, and it's based on the Macedonian Law on border control. Neither Macedonian nor EU/Schengen passports are stamped.